# aws batch job stuck in runnable with high memory requirement for jobdefinition

Tags: amazon-web-services, memory, batch-processing

I have a batch job that runs successfully when the memory requirement is <15GB but gets stuck in runnable when more memory is required.

[Batch troubleshooting](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/troubleshooting.html) says that this might happen because of insufficient resoureces:

> Jobs Stuck in RUNNABLE Status
>
> Insufficient resources
>
> If your job definitions specify more CPU or
>   memory resources than your compute resources can allocate, then your
>   jobs will never be placed. For example, if your job specifies 4 GiB of
>   memory, and your compute resources have less than that, then the job
>   cannot be placed on those compute resources. In this case, you must
>   reduce the specified memory in your job definition or add larger
>   compute resources to your environment.

However, the `ComputeResorces` `InstanceTypes` is set to `optimal` and the batch appears to select different instance types (e.g. `r4.large`) based on changes to memory requirements. So I do not understand why batch is unable to select an appropriate resource with sufficient memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jobs eventually moved out of `Runnable` and completed successfully (the largest job that ran used 64GB). So it looks like the Compute Resources were able to be set up properly with `InstanceType` of `optimal`.

Answer (score 2):

One thing that might be happening is that your AWS account might be hitting EC2 instance limits. This will prevent batch from being able to launch instances that are large enough to fit your job.

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is shell into your EC2 instance and run `docker stats` while it's running.  This will show the actual container memory/cpu utilization.

[image]

I found, for example, a docker process that ran on my computer at 900mb took 4gb in ECS (wtf?).

Also, if your AWS Batch compute environment is set to `managed by AWS` then it will autoscale instances to fit your needs until you hit a hard limit such as `maximum vcpu`.  The host machine should never run out of memory because the containers themselves have pre-allocated memory.  The containers will run out of memory before the host machine will.